# How to set the value of extent.properties dynamically using ExtentCucumberAdapter7 and cucumber

Tags: cucumber, extentreports

Suppose, extent.properties has `extent.reporter.html.out=outputPath/QAAutomationReport.html`

In runner class

@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}

It read the properties value extent.properties but I have two runner class and need to change the value of extent.reporter.html.out before run.